# Azure devops RestAPI System.Description

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Doing some tests with the Azure Devops RestAPI to make releasenotes from a powershell script.
I can't seem to get back the System.Description field from a workitem. Probably has to do with the fact that it is an HTML Editor field

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Azure devops RestAPI System.Description

We could use the REST API [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the workiten detailed info:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0
```

The return result:

[image]

**Note:**

- It is general **HTML formatted value**, for example `<div></div> <B></B>`.
- You need set value in the Description field, otherwise the field `System.Description` does not exist.

My powershell test scripts:

```
$connectionToken="$(PAT)"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<YourOrganizationName>/<YourTestProject>/_apis/wit/workItems/184?api-version=6.0" 

$WorkItemInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

Write-Host "SystemDescription= $($WorkItemInfo.fields."System.Description" )"
```

**Note2:**

- When getting the value of the `System.Description`, we need to add double quotes to `System.Description`.

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem existed between chair and keyboard. Apparently I was querying a Bug, which has repro steps and not a description.